# Static inner class compile results

Tags: java, compilation

```
public class InnerClass {
    private static class B{}
}
```

What are the corresponding *.class files* that this compiles to?

Somewhere I heard the answer as it compiles to

- *InnerClass.class*
- *B.class*

But after I actually tried it, it was

- *InnerClass$B.class*
- *InnerClass.class*.

---

**Any method it can be compiled to:** *InnerClass.class* and *B.class*?
*(This is from an interview.)*

Comment: "Inner class definitions produce additional class files. These class files have names combining the inner and outer class names, such as MyClass$MyInnerClass.class." [javac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: According to the answers below, I would assume that the interviewer actually made mistakes in this question. There are no way unless it's public top class, it could be compiled separately.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `B` is a member class in `InnerClass`, this is not possible. The `$` sign is generated by the compiler to indicate that this class is a nested class.

You need to define B as a top-level class in order to generate a `B.class` file.

Comment: According to the answers below, I would assume that the interviewer actually made mistakes in this question. There is no way unless it's public top class, it could be compiled separately